# Query workflow tasks based on custom property with other criteria than equals

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have the need to construct a `WorkflowTaskQuery` with a custom workflow model date as criteria. The criteria needs to be `"currentDate >= myCustomDate"`.

I have noticed that it is possible to add custom properties to the `WorkflowTaskQuery` but looking into the implementation it seems like those properties all are added as equals-criterias. (reference(4.2.x): `org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiWorkflowEngine.addTaskPropertiesToQuery)`

To get all active tasks and do the filtering on the returned result will not be a good approach since there will be thousands of running workflow tasks in this implementation.

The only other approach I can think of would be to subclass both `WorkflowTaskQuery` and `ActivitiWorkflowEngine` and rewrite some private methods (like `createRuntimeTaskQuery`) and handle my special cases on my own there. (Activiti has methods like greaterThan and so on when searching for tasks based on variables....)

If anyone have any better suggestions, please feel free to share them with me :)

Answer (score 1):

We are implementing a solution that drives Activiti using the Rest interface and have successfully implemented task queries using the POST /rest/service/query/task

The body of the request contains the conditions and the operator to use in query can have the following values: "equals", "notEquals", "equalsIgnoreCase", "notEqualsIgnoreCase", "lessThan", "greaterThan", "lessThanOrEquals", "greaterThanOrEquals" and "like".

Now, with that said.....I'm not sure I understand your query.
currentData >= customDate, obviously currentDate is self explanatory, but is customDate a process instance variable or a task local variable? It may impact the format of the query.

Comment: That date is a date from our custom workflow model for the task. So it would be a task local variable.